# How to implement custom validations for methods called by other methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, custom-validators

I create a `Subscription` for a `User` via the method `.create_subscription(plan_title)`.

That method checks that it's possible to subscribe (not oversubscribed plan or archived subscription) via the method `.plan_subscribable?(plan)`.

This method does either return `true` or `false`, but I would like it to return an error message as well that could be passed to the user if `false`.

**How and where do I implement these validation errors?**

```
class User

  def plan_subscribable?(plan)
    users_subscribed = Subscription.where(plan_id: plan.id).size

    return false unless users_subscribed <= plan.quantity
    return false unless plan.archived == false
    return true
  end

  def create_subscription(plan_title)
    plan = Plan.where(title: plan_title).first

    if plan_subscribable?(plan)
      Subscription.create(...)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: You need to clarify what it is that you want to raise or return instead of `false`. I'd also suggest you state what it is that you've tried/considered or at least read about how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify `plan_subscribable?` to return a boolean `true` **or** a *string* containing the specific error message:

```
def plan_subscribable?(plan)
  return 'The number of users cannot be higher than the plan quantity' unless users_subscribed <= plan.quantity
  return 'Archived plans are not subscribable' unless plan.archived == false
  return true
end
```

Then, evaluate whether the returned value from `plan_subscribable?` is `true`. If it is not, the statement is *implicitly false* and you can use the returned value as the error message:

```
def create_subscription(plan_title)
  plan = Plan.where(title: plan_title).first

  subscribable_or_error = plan_subscribable?(plan)
  if subscribable_or_error === true
    Subscription.create(...)
  else
    error_message = subscribable_or_error
  end
end
```